# Can't sync libraries to OneDrive, "Your IT admin no longer allows you to sync"

Tags: sharepoint-online, library, onedrive

When I click on "Add shortcut to OneDrive" on a document library, at first it appears to succeed, but then I see a sync error in OneDrive:

[image: A OneDrive tray flyout showing an error: A shortcut no longer works. Your IT admin no longer allows you to sync [library].]

I am the IT admin. I don't recall ever changing any setting to prohibit OneDrive sync. How do I enable it?

Answer (score 2):

Under **library settings**, go to **Advanced settings** and set "Allow items from this document library to be downloaded to offline clients?" to *Yes*.

For some reason, when I imported the library via ShareGate, this setting defaulted to No.

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/sharepoint/comments/14mwz8p/comment/jqh9nfb/